# the declared package does not match the expected package

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, import

I have imported a maven project from git.
As the sources were not seen I add the src directories as sources.
Maven compiles correctly. But In Eclipse I have the error.

> Tthe declared package com.mypackage does not match the expected package src.main.java.com.mypackage

I have another error when updating import and I think it is a result of this :

> project roots is not on it's project build path"

Comment: Which way do you choose in which Eclipse IDE of which version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the traditional Maven structure (which this project seems to have), `src` isn't the root of the sources. Under it, you'll find (up to) two folders:

1. `src/main/java` is the source root for the "production" code
2. `src/test/java` is the source root for the test code.

Answer (score 0):

See [Maven / Introduction to the Standard Directory Layout](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html):

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| `src/main/java` | Application/Library sources |
| ... | ... |